# problems about using apt-get install build-essential and make C source file

Tags: c, linux

I'm going to write C code on Ubuntu 17.10, when I was about to use `make` command to compile, the terminal message was:

```
dophia@ubuntu:~/Downloads/datalab-handout$ make world
The program 'make' can be found in the following packages:
 * make
 * make-guile
Try: sudo apt install <selected package>
```

I googled and got a solution

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Then I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree    
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7 libalgorithm-diff-perl    
  libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan4    
  libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dbg libc6-dev libcilkrts5    
  libfakeroot libgcc-7-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libmpx2 libquadmath0    
  libstdc++-7-dev libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev
Suggested packages:
  debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-7-multilib gcc-7-doc    
  libstdc++6-7-dbg gcc-multilib autoconf automake libtool flex bison   
  gcc-doc gcc-7-multilib gcc-7-locales libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg   
  libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan4-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg   
  libubsan0-dbg libcilkrts5-dbg libmpx2-dbg libquadmath0-dbg 
  glibc-doc libstdc++-7-doc make-doc   
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  build-essential dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7   
  libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl    
  libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan4 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev   
  libcilkrts5 libfakeroot libgcc-7-dev libitm1 liblsan0 libmpx2   
  libquadmath0 libstdc++-7-dev libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev make   
  manpages-dev  
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc6 libc6-dbg
2 upgraded, 27 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded.
Need to get 34.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 116 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main amd64 libc6-dbg amd64 2.26-0ubuntu2.1 [4,997 kB]
**Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main amd64 libc6 amd64 2.26-0ubuntu2.1 [2,780 kB]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main amd64 libc6 amd64 2.26-0ubuntu2.1
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:b90d28f35eedf6fd218a90bf4c0634f5d60686e2f2ed38c4e283f581fbe8eef2
   - SHA1:54c460b9ca8746481342047236c6c3ceaec877a4 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:3069cbb5207a71f297b741c025de42ca [weak]
   - Filesize:2779898 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:0ed5fbdf0f3dcce4e428dd34b063043abcc8e56fed895fd58cb813fece65beb1
   - SHA1:f9b0e80321aa9b4a29fc7414072374366ecd5068 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:9a27e8f5f78d7c271cdc771f26a45e70 [weak]
   - Filesize:69466 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Wed, 17 Jan 2018 10:09:06 +0000**
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/main amd64 libc6 amd64 2.26-0ubuntu2.1 [2,780 kB]
blah blah...
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 manpages-dev all 4.13-3 [2,202 kB]
Fetched 34.4 MB in 4min 28s (128 kB/s)                                
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 126030 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dbg_2.26-0ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dbg:amd64 (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) over (2.26-0ubuntu2) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.26-0ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6:amd64 (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) over (2.26-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libc6:amd64 (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libc-dev-bin.
(Reading database ... 126030 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libc-dev-bin_2.26-0ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc-dev-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-libc-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../01-linux-libc-dev_4.13.0-25.29_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.13.0-25.29) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libc6-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libc6-dev_2.26-0ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev:amd64 (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libitm1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libitm1_7.2.0-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libitm1:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libatomic1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libatomic1_7.2.0-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libatomic1:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libasan4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libasan4_7.2.0-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libasan4:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblsan0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../06-liblsan0_7.2.0-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking liblsan0:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtsan0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libtsan0_7.2.0-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtsan0:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libubsan0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libubsan0_7.2.0-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libubsan0:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcilkrts5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libcilkrts5_7.2.0-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcilkrts5:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmpx2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libmpx2_7.2.0-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmpx2:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libquadmath0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libquadmath0_7.2.0-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libquadmath0:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgcc-7-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../12-libgcc-7-dev_7.2.0-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgcc-7-dev:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gcc-7.
Preparing to unpack .../13-gcc-7_7.2.0-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-7 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gcc.
Preparing to unpack .../14-gcc_4%3a7.2.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc (4:7.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libstdc++-7-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../15-libstdc++-7-dev_7.2.0-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libstdc++-7-dev:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package g++-7.
Preparing to unpack .../16-g++-7_7.2.0-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking g++-7 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package g++.
Preparing to unpack .../17-g++_4%3a7.2.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking g++ (4:7.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package make.
Preparing to unpack .../18-make_4.1-9.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking make (4.1-9.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package dpkg-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../19-dpkg-dev_1.18.24ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking dpkg-dev (1.18.24ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package build-essential.
Preparing to unpack .../20-build-essential_12.4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking build-essential (12.4ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfakeroot:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../21-libfakeroot_1.21-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfakeroot:amd64 (1.21-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fakeroot.
Preparing to unpack .../22-fakeroot_1.21-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fakeroot (1.21-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-diff-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../23-libalgorithm-diff-perl_1.19.03-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-perl (1.19.03-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../24-libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl_0.04-4build3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (0.04-4build3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libalgorithm-merge-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../25-libalgorithm-merge-perl_0.08-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libalgorithm-merge-perl (0.08-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package manpages-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../26-manpages-dev_4.13-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking manpages-dev (4.13-3) ...
Setting up libquadmath0:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libatomic1:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Setting up make (4.1-9.1) ...
Setting up libc6-dbg:amd64 (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up libasan4:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libcilkrts5:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libubsan0:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libtsan0:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.13.0-25.29) ...
Setting up liblsan0:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libmpx2:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Setting up dpkg-dev (1.18.24ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libfakeroot:amd64 (1.21-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-diff-perl (1.19.03-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Setting up libc-dev-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up manpages-dev (4.13-3) ...
Setting up libc6-dev:amd64 (2.26-0ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up libitm1:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Setting up fakeroot (1.21-1ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/fakeroot-sysv to provide /usr/bin/fakeroot (fakeroot) in auto mode
Setting up libgcc-7-dev:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libstdc++-7-dev:amd64 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-merge-perl (0.08-3) ...
Setting up libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl (0.04-4build3) ...
Setting up gcc-7 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Setting up g++-7 (7.2.0-8ubuntu3) ...
Setting up gcc (4:7.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up g++ (4:7.2.0-1ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/g++ to provide /usr/bin/c++ (c++) in auto mode
Setting up build-essential (12.4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2) ...
```

*There was the error message above:*

```
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main amd64 libc6 amd64 2.26-0ubuntu2.1 [2,780 kB]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main amd64 libc6 amd64 2.26-0ubuntu2.1
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - SHA256:b90d28f35eedf6fd218a90bf4c0634f5d60686e2f2ed38c4e283f581fbe8eef2
   - SHA1:54c460b9ca8746481342047236c6c3ceaec877a4 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:3069cbb5207a71f297b741c025de42ca [weak]
   - Filesize:2779898 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:0ed5fbdf0f3dcce4e428dd34b063043abcc8e56fed895fd58cb813fece65beb1
   - SHA1:f9b0e80321aa9b4a29fc7414072374366ecd5068 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:9a27e8f5f78d7c271cdc771f26a45e70 [weak]
   - Filesize:69466 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Wed, 17 Jan 2018 10:09:06 +0000
```

Then I tried to `make` world.c, which is the simpest code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
  printf(hello!);
}
```

In the end, I got an error after I excecuted the command: `make world` 
Here is the result:

```
dophia@ubuntu:~/Downloads/datalab-handout$ make world
gcc -O -Wall -m32    world.c   -o world
In file included from world.c:1:0:
/usr/include/stdio.h:27:10: fatal error: bits/libc-header-start.h: No such file or directory
 #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'world' failed
make: *** [world] Error 1
```

How can I fix this problem ? I looked for solutions for a long time, Thanks everyone in advance!

Update:

I figured out where the problem was.
First, the installation was not complete, I reinstalled using another software source near my location other than in US.

Then I found the error still existed(not world.c,another program in CSAPP datalab), this error occurred when I was trying to compile 32-bit program on my 64-bit Ubuntu, so I installed 32-bit C lirbrary, here it is: `sudo apt-get install gcc-multillib`, and that works! thanks everyone.

Comment: Reinstall the failed packages.

Comment: I'm a novice, how can i reinstall those packages in this case?  Very thanks!

Comment: @J.Butter run and run and rerun `apt-get update` and make sure it didn't fail. After that, *install* `build-essential`, it most probably didnät get *installed completely at all*.

Comment: All in all, this is not really as much of a pure programming tools question, but better a question for Ask Ubuntu about how to get `build-essential` installed properly. Yourswasn't installed correctly!

Comment: agree with all above, AND `printf(hello!)`, should be `printf("hello!\n")`. (Leave as is to see a compiler error message once you get the `#include`s problem sorted ;-)). Good luck.